# How to save xy coordinates from a fviz_nbclust plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph that takes over 20 minutes to generate in R. It is an 'elbow plot' from the fviz_nbclust package. Is there a way to save the x and y coordinates from the graph to manipulate further in a ggplot graph instead of waiting 20 minutes every time I need to edit/format the graph?

e.g. using the USA Arrests data set in R

```
#load data
df <- USArrests

#remove rows with missing values
df <- na.omit(df)

#scale each variable to have a mean of 0 and sd of 1
df <- scale(df)

library(cluster)
library(factoextra)

#create plot of number of clusters vs total within sum of squares
fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss")

#Save coordinates of graph to be plotted on a ggplot graph here...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - If I get it correctly you want to access data points in the plot (x: number of clusters, and y: twss). So, just save the plot in a variable and access the data dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)

#load data
df <- USArrests

#remove rows with missing values
df <- na.omit(df)

#scale each variable to have a mean of 0 and sd of 1
df <- scale(df)

fcl <- fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss")
fcl$data
#   clusters         y
#1         1 196.00000
#2         2 102.86240
#3         3  78.32327
#4         4  56.40317
#5         5  70.83569
#6         6  45.30784
#7         7  39.03188
#8         8  39.00701
#9         9  32.24437
#10       10  28.69826

# simple plot using ggplot
ggplot(fcl$data, aes(clusters, y, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + labs(title="Elbow plot to find the optimal number of clusters", x="number of clusters", y="total within sum of square")
```

plot:
[image]